# Ler um arquivo txt, inserir em um array e mostrar em um textbox no C#

Tags: c#, array, winforms, lista

Eu necessito abrir o arquivo txt com os dados já inseridos com três colunas e separadas por ';' e após abrir o arquivo eu insiro em uma Array com List, salvo os dados e preciso que os valores inseridos dentro do arquivo apareçam em uma textbox. Porém eu preciso pegar um valor exato e/ou próximo do valor digitado em uma textbox anterior e esses valor está na coluna 1 do arquivo e quando o valor é selecionado eu necessito que ele me mostra o valor da coluna 3 da mesma linha do valor selecionado.

Eu já consegui abrir o arquivo, jogar os dados do arquivo na Array, porém ele não me retorna os valores da coluna 3 que necessito.
Finalizei esse código, porém ele me mostra a última linha do arquivo com as três colunas.
Acredito que o erro esteja a partir do foreach, pois ele lê apenas a última linha. E não sei como fazer um If (se é o If que necessito fazer) para que ele leia o valor da textbox anterior e leia o valor próximo no arquivo e selecione a coluna 3.
Já tentei fazer if ou inserir as iterações dentro do do código no foreach, mas nem sucesso.

Obs.: Já li vários sites/fóruns sobre isso, porém nenhum foi de acordo com que necessito.

No arquivo txt está assim os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo: o valor digitado na textbox anterior deu 173,10 logo o valor próximo no arquivo txt é 172,0585213 então, eu quero que ele selecione esse valor e mostre o valor da terceira coluna (16) na textbox seguinte.

Vou inserir o meu código abaixo:

```
    List<string> lista = new List<string>(); 

        string dados = (@"C: .... .txt"); // // caminho do documento em C: com a extensão em .txt
        string linha; // //declara uma variável para receber linha por linha do doc.

        using (StreamReader Str = new StreamReader(dados)) // a leitura do arquivo.
        {
            while ((linha = Str.ReadLine()) != null) //cria um loop para adicionar linha por linha do doc até sua ultima linha.
            {
                lista.Add(linha);
            }

           for (int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++) // Percorro o array e para cada linha.
            {
                foreach (var item in lista)
                {

                    var coluna1 = Convert.ToInt32(item[0]);
                    var coluna3 = Convert.ToInt32(item[2]);

                    var valores = File.ReadAllLines(dados).Select(linha => linha.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        .Where(Split => Split.Length >= 3).Select(Split => Split[2]).ToList();
                    Txtbox2.Text = (item).ToString();

                }

            }
```

Comment: Tá bem confuso... é TextBox mesmo ou ListBox/ComboBox? Poderia ser um text box e um list box, onde os items da lista são filtrados baseado no valor digitado no text box, seria isso?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `Convert.ToInt32(item[0]);` ler o primeiro caractere? Porque você está lendo duas vezes o arquivo????

Comment: @Kiritonito Isso mesmo, Eu quero que ele filtre no arquivo o valor digitado no textbox anterior  e e mostre o valor na textbox seguinte (mas seria o valor da terceira coluna, pois o ele irá filtrar o valor da coluna 1).

Vou esclarecer melhor na pergunta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Eu não teria que inserir  os itens (colunas) do meu arquivo txt para ele fazer fazer o filtro? Dizendo que a coluna 1 é [0] e a coluna 3 é o [2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei via console application, mas é plenamente possível usar essa classe no winforms.

```
class Arquivo_Dados
{
    private List<string[]> _data;

    private List<double> _fmtData;

    // Chamar apenas uma vez, não tem pq ler o arquivo várias vezes.
    public void Load() {
        _data = File.ReadAllLines("H:/arquivo.txt").Select(
            // l = 43,01463032;    46,8918;      9,5;
            // output = ["43,01463032", "46,8918", "9,5"]
            l => l.Split(';').Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray()
        ).ToList();

        _fmtData = _data.Select(l => double.Parse(l[0])).ToList();
    }

    public (int lineIndex, string valor)? SearchData(string input) {
        if (!double.TryParse(input, out double di)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Se o elemento for menor ou igual que o primeiro,
        // retornamos ele.
        if (di <= _fmtData[0]) {
            return (0, _data[0][2]);
        }

        // Se o elemento for maior ou igual que o último,
        // retornamos ele.
        if (di >= _fmtData[^1]) {
            return (_fmtData.Count - 1, _data[^1][2]);
        }

        // Retornamos o que tiver a menor diferença.
        var difs = _fmtData.Select(savedData => Math.Abs(savedData - di)).ToList();
        var idx = difs.IndexOf(difs.Min());

        return (idx, _data[idx][2]);
    }

    // Retorna somente a coluna 3.
    public string SearchDataValueOnly(string input) {
        if (!double.TryParse(input, out double di)) {
            return "";
        }

        // Se o elemento for menor ou igual que o primeiro,
        // retornamos ele.
        if (di <= _fmtData[0]) {
            return _data[0][2];
        }

        // Se o elemento for maior ou igual que o último,
        // retornamos ele.
        if (di >= _fmtData[^1]) {
            return _data[^1][2];
        }

        // Retornamos o que tiver a menor diferença.
        var difs = _fmtData.Select(savedData => Math.Abs(savedData - di)).ToList();
        var idx = difs.IndexOf(difs.Min());

        return _data[idx][2];
    }
}
```

Meu arquivo txt:

```
43,01463032;    46,8918;      9,5;
60,65734978;    67,14495;     1,5;
88,88570093;    90,7425;      13;
113,5855082;    149,5044;     14,5;
141,6293991;    183,29985;    16;
242,3097816;    261,6327;     19;
```

App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var lk = new Arquivo_Dados();
        lk.Load();
        
        var r = lk.SearchData("512,50");
        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Valor: {1}", r?.lineIndex, r?.valor);
        
        var r = lk.SearchData("10,688");
        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Valor: {1}", r?.lineIndex, r?.valor);
        
        var r = lk.SearchData("64,355");
        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Valor: {1}", r?.lineIndex, r?.valor);
        
        var r = lk.SearchData("117,92");
        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Valor: {1}", r?.lineIndex, r?.valor);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Index: 5; Valor: 19
Index: 0; Valor: 9,5
Index: 1; Valor: 1,5
Index: 3; Valor: 14,5
```

#### Observação

Como você vai filtrar dados em resposta a um evento de um textbox, isto é, evento vindo do usuário, seria bom você implementar algum sistema de *debounce* no textbox onde o usuário digita, evitando que o pc exploda.

Outro ponto é que eu coloquei o tuple como nullable, para caso o usuário enviar um valor inválido, embora ali no meu exemplo eu não esteja fazendo a verificação, seria bom você fazer.

#### Edit - ComboBox

Eu adicionei essas duas funções na classe arquivo dados:

```
public string[] ListarColuna3() {
    return _data.Select(d => d[2]).ToArray();
}

public string[] BuscarPelaColuna3(int index) {
    // return _data.Where(d => d[2] == input).FirstOrDefault();
    return _data[index];
}
```

No meu form:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    _arqDados = new Arquivo_Dados();
    _arqDados.Load();

    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(_arqDados.ListarColuna3());
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var linha = _arqDados.BuscarPelaColuna3(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);

    textBox1.Text = linha[0];
    textBox2.Text = linha[1];
}
```

Esse `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` é um evento do ComboBox. Você pode adicioná-lo pela janela *properties* ou via código: `comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;`. Como o nome sugere, vai ser chamado quando o índice selecionado for alterado.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda dada até agora. Fiz exatamente o seu código, mudando apenas alguma nomenclaturas.
Porém no momento de ler os dados da classe e mostrar no meu textbox,ele aparece a linha que está o valor e o valor da coluna 3 (quero que apenas mostre o valor da coluna 3, sem o index. 

`var Arq_Dados = new Arquivo_Dados();
Arq_Dados.Load();

var num = Arq_Dados.SearchDados(txtFcmin.Text);
txtDc.Text = (num?.lineIndex, num?.valor).ToString(); ` 

Porém seu eu tirar **num?.lineIndex** ele dá erro, acredito que tenho que alterar algo na classe, correto??

Comment: @Cristina Você poderia fazer assim: `txtDc.Text = num?.valor;`. Mas como você não vai precisar do index, adicionei a função na resposta que retorna apenas a coluna 3. Você não precisa usar o `ToString()` pq a coluna retornada já é uma string.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela sua ajuda e pelas dicas, deu certo aqui!

Gratidão!! 
​​​​​​​

Comment: Estou otimizando ainda o form com os dados, pois é um form de cálculos. E alterei para ao invés de mostrar na textbox mostrar em uma combobox, deu certo. E eu gostaria de saber se eu consigo selecionar um valor da combobox(coluna 3) e ele me retornar os valores da coluna 1 ou 2 nas textbox, (fazer o inverso agora). Eu testei, mas ele acaba duplicando os valores e eu travei nessa lógica não sei se é possível um if, else. Ou eu teria que deixar na texbox mesmo o resultado e programar a combobox? É que eu gostaria de deixar as duas aplicações em um local apenas.

Comment: No combobox está apenas o valor da coluna 3, certo? No `Arquivo_Dados`, você cria uma função que aceite um único parâmetro (tipo string), e põe lá: `return _data.Where(d => d[2] == valorColuna3).FirstOrDefault();`. Ele vai retornar todo o array da linha (ou nulo, se não encontrar). Com o resultado, é só setar o texto dos textbox pra cada índice do resultado.

Comment: @Cristina adicionei um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigada!!

Comment: Fiquei com uma dúvida na questão de pegar apenas o valores maiores iguais ao valor da coluna 1. Seria esse mesmo código? `if (di >= _fmtData[^1]) { return  _data[^1][2];}`
Porém eu teria que alterar isso, correto? `var difs = _fmtData.Select(savedData => Math.Abs(savedData - di)).ToList();
        var idx = difs.IndexOf(difs.Min()):`
Estou tentando entender para alterar esse **Min()**. Correto?

Comment: Você quer retornar apenas se o valor da coluna 1 for maior ou igual ao input? Se for, vou deixar um print com um código, alterando a função `SearchData`.

https://ibb.co/6BZxdzd.

Se o input que tiver que ser maior ou igual, só inverte lá no código para `di >= fd`.

Comment: Isso, quero retornar apenas o valores maiores iguais ao input (textbox). Este código eu insiro após o if, correto? Ele está dando erro, segue o print: (https://ibb.co/0ZGBVL5) E o erro: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' to 'int'` O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado??

Comment: Segue: https://ibb.co/kJ16059 . Ali, ele vai buscar a menor diferença entre os valores que são maiores que o input.

Comment: Muito obrigada, me ajudou muito !!!

Comment: Na minha combobox quando eu seleciono o valor (coluna 3) para ele procurar novamente no arquivo, ele não me retorna o valor da (coluna 2) da mesma linha, ele retorna o próximo valor da linha. 
Está acontecendo isso por conta que, eu alterei para retornar apenas os maiores ou iguais?
Mas era para isso acontecendo.

Comment: Conseguiria me ajudar com o erro acima que comentei ??

Comment: De fato, não era pra acontecer... não tenho acesso ao código, não tem como eu saber o que acontece.