# C# - Leitura de arquivo txt e retornar valor no textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, txt, combobox

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que a partir de uma seleção do Combobox, ele lê o arquivo txt (contendo duas colunas) e me retorna o valor da mesma linha porém da coluna 1 (a coluna 2 seria do valor do Combobox).
Eu consigo com que me retorne os valores, porém está retornando o valores da coluna 1, porém da próxima linha.

Já consegui fazer com que retorne outros valores de outros textbox, combobox, pois há a mesma aplicação, porém apenas desse que não estou conseguindo.

Já tentei fazer de tudo, pesquisar, li fóruns, mas não consigo achar onde está o meu erro.

Código na classe:

```
public class Arquivo_Dados
{
    public List<string[]> Dados;
    public List<double> fmtDados;

    public void LoadDados() // Chama o arquivo e lê todas linhas separando por ';'. 
    {
        Dados = File.ReadAllLines(@"caminho do meu arquivo").Select(l => l.Split(';').Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray()).ToList();

        fmtDados = Dados.Select(lDados => double.Parse(lDados[0])).ToList();
    }

    public string ReceberMaiorValorDiametro(string input) // Ler os dados do arquivo da coluna 1 retornar os valores da coluna 2 (Diametro - mm).
    {
        if (!double.TryParse(input, out double dbDiam))
        {
            return null;
        }

        int index = 0;
        double min = double.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < fmtDados.Count; i++)
        {
            if (fmtDados[i] < dbDiam) // Se menor que o valor a entrada (Textbox), ignora.
            {
                continue;
            }

            var difDiam = Math.Abs(fmtDados[i] - dbDiam); // Diferença entre a entrada (Textbox) e o que está no arquivo. 

            if (difDiam < min) // Se a diferença for menor que a anterior, retorna.
            {
                min = difDiam;
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return Dados[index][1]; //Retorna a coluna 2.
    }

    public string ReceberMaiorValorCarga(string input) // Ler os dados do arquivo da coluna 2 retornar os valores da coluna 1 (Carga - kN).
    {
        if (!double.TryParse(input, out double dbCarga))
        {
            return null;
        }

        int index = 0;
        double min = double.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < fmtDados.Count; i++)
        {
            if (fmtDados[i] < dbCarga) // Se menor que o valor a entrada (Textbox), ignora.
            {
                continue;
            }

            var difCarga = Math.Abs(fmtDados[i] - dbCarga); // Diferença entre a entrada (Textbox) e o que está no arquivo. 

            if (difCarga < min) // Se a diferença for menor que a anterior, retorna.
            {
                min = difCarga;
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return Dados[index][0]; //Retorna a coluna 1.
    }

     public string[] ListarColuna2()
     {
         return Dados.Select(dCol2 => dCol2[1]).ToArray();
     }

     public string[] BuscarColuna2(int index)
     {
         return Dados[index];
     }
}
```

Os códigos `ReceberMaiorValorDiametro` e `ReceberMaiorValorCarga`estão dando certo apenas o `ListarColuna2()` e `BuscarColuna2` Não está me retornando corretamente a linha que eu quero (a coluna está certo).

No formulário estou estou chamando eles:

```cs
var numDiam = Arq_Dados.ReceberMaiorValorDiametro(txtFc.Text);
ValorDc = double.Parse(cmbNumeros.Text = numDiam?.ToString());

var numCarga = Arq_Dados.ReceberMaiorValorCarga(txtFc.Text);
FcAdopted = double.Parse(txtNum.Text = numCarga?.ToString());
```

Os valores do numDiam gerados estão indo para o combobox, e há outros valores já cadastrados na combobox (são mesmos valores no arquivo txt) E quero que a partir de uma seleção no combobox ele leia o arquivo novamente e me retorna os valores (ele está me retornando a coluna certa, porém a linha não, está me retornando a próxima linha).

Código que inseri no Combobox:

```cs
var Arq_Dados = new Arquivo_Dados();
Arq_Dados.LoadDados();

cmbNumeros.Items.IndexOf(Arq_Dados.ListarColuna2());

var Coluna1 = Arq_Dados.BuscarColuna2(cmbNumeros.SelectedIndex);
txtNum.Text = Coluna1[0];
```

Arquivo txt:

```
460,089;        26;
711,07785;      32;
1014,5502       38;
1174,7475;      42;
```

Ex.: eu seleciono o número 26 no Combobox e ele teria que me retornar o 460,089. Mas ele está me retornando o 711,07785.

Comment: Não dá pra entender o que o seu código faz. É melhor [edit] e postar apenas a parte relevante do código.

Comment: @LINQ Ok, irei editar. É que os restante do código são para ler o arquivo txt e me retornar os valores, e está compilando certo. Apenas esse código que não está me retornando a linha certa. Acabei de editar se puder me ajudar, ficar muito grata!

Comment: @JéfBueno Poderia me ajudar? Acho que é um erro simples, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar.

Comment: Hoje mais tarde terei uns minutos livres e lerei a pergunta com calma.

Comment: Acabei de reler a pergunta e tentei reproduzir o problema localmente e não consegui fazê-lo. Com as informações que você passou na pergunta, o código funciona normalmente. Minha dica pra você é: tente isolar o problema, remova todo o código desnecessário para entendimento dele (é até melhor criar um novo código para testar). Provavelmente fazendo isto você já vai conseguir resolver o problema sozinha, mas caso não conseguir, poderá [edit] a pergunta e deixar um exemplo reproduzível.

Comment: @JéfBueno Irei fazer isso, obrigada pela dica. Não sei se isso te ajuda, esse pergunta que criei veio de uma outra que já tinha feito e as duas se interligam Vou te passar aqui, acredito que possa entender melhor. Pois essa pergunta é o complemento da outra (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509608/ler-um-arquivo-txt-inserir-em-um-array-e-mostrar-em-um-textbox-no-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Os valores do numDiam gerados estão indo para o combobox, **e há outros valores já cadastrados na combobox** (são mesmos valores no arquivo txt)

O problema deve estar aí. Você está inserindo todos os valores do arquivo no combobox e depois adicionando mais a entrada do txt (`numDiam`)?

Tá meio nebuloso, não sei se você está atualizando o arquivo e carregando ele várias vezes e etc. Se você não estiver adicionando items novamente no combobox, não era para acontecer esse erro.

De qualquer forma, você pode alterar o método `BuscarColuna2` e fazer ele procurar por valor ao invés de index.

```
public string[] BuscarColuna2(string valor) {
    // Se quiser usar Linq...
    // return Dados.Where(d => d[1] == valor).FirstOrDefault();
    
    // tradicional.
    for (int i = 0; i < Dados.Count; i++) {
        if (Dados[i][1] == valor) {
            return Dados[i];
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}


// NO EVENTO DO COMBOBOX...
var coluna1 = Arq_Dados.BuscarColuna2(cmbNumeros.SelectedItem as string);
```

Comment: Deu certo!
Muito obrigada pela ajuda!